# SQL Server combine multiple queries on same table into single resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I've seen similar questions but can't quite find a solution to this problem. Bear with the mess of tables, as the question should be? fairly straightforward.

I have the following table.

```
LDTime                      Value
2013-07-24 00:00:00.000     14.85
2013-07-24 00:00:00.000     1.339
2013-07-24 00:15:00.000     95.9
2013-07-24 00:15:00.000     1.285
2013-07-24 00:30:00.000     160
2013-07-24 00:30:00.000     0.952
```

Rows 1,3,and 5 are one type of data. 2, 4, and 6 are another type. I have the following queries which can retrieve the types based on a filter criterion:

```
SELECT 
    A.LDTime, A.Value As AValue
FROM      
    Table7 G 
INNER JOIN
     Table1 A 
INNER JOIN
     Table2 B ON A.DataSetIdx = B.DataSetIdx 
INNER JOIN
     Table3 C ON B.RetrievalIdx = C.RetrievalIdx ON G.ActionIdx = C.ActionIdx 
INNER JOIN
     Table4 D ON G.SpatialRefIdx = D.SpatialRefIdx 
INNER JOIN
     Table5 E 
INNER JOIN
     Table6 F ON E.StationIdx = F.StationIDx ON D.SpatialRefIdx = E.SpatialRefIdx
WHERE 
     F.StationIDx = 1 
     AND A.ParameterIdx = 18
     AND A.LDTime BETWEEN '2013-7-24' AND '2013-7-25'
ORDER 
     BY A.LDTime


SELECT 
    A.LDTime, A.Value As BValue
FROM
    Table7 G 
INNER JOIN
    Table1 A 
INNER JOIN
    Table2 B ON A.DataSetIdx = B.DataSetIdx 
INNER JOIN
    Table3 C ON B.RetrievalIdx = C.RetrievalIdx ON G.ActionIdx = C.ActionIdx 
INNER JOIN
    Table4 D ON G.SpatialRefIdx = D.SpatialRefIdx 
INNER JOIN
    Table5 E 
INNER JOIN
    Table6 F ON E.StationIdx = F.StationIDx ON D.SpatialRefIdx = E.SpatialRefIdx
WHERE 
    F.StationIDx = 1 
    AND A.ParameterIdx = 19
    AND A.LDTime BETWEEN '2013-7-24' AND '2013-7-25'
ORDER BY 
     A.LDTime
```

Note that I change only one filter variable (`ParameterIdx`) between the two queries, which distinguishes the type of data stored in the value column.

How can I combine the queries to produce one resultset? (Alternatively, I am using stored procedures, so this could be done in multiple queries).

```
LDTime                      AValue   BValue
2013-07-24 00:00:00.000     14.85    1.339
2013-07-24 00:15:00.000     95.9     1.285
2013-07-24 00:30:00.000     160      0.952
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT a.LDTime
     , Avalue = MAX(CASE WHEN A.ParameterIdx = 18 THEN A.Value END)
     , BValue = MAX(CASE WHEN A.ParameterIdx = 19 THEN A.Value END)
FROM         Table7 G INNER JOIN
Table1 A INNER JOIN
Table2 B ON A.DataSetIdx = B.DataSetIdx INNER JOIN
Table3 C ON B.RetrievalIdx = C.RetrievalIdx ON G.ActionIdx = C.ActionIdx INNER JOIN
Table4 D ON G.SpatialRefIdx = D.SpatialRefIdx INNER JOIN
Table5 E INNER JOIN
Table6 F ON E.StationIdx = F.StationIDx ON D.SpatialRefIdx = E.SpatialRefIdx
WHERE F.StationIDx = 1 AND A.ParameterIdx in (18, 19)
AND A.LDTime BETWEEN '2013-7-24' AND '2013-7-25'
GROUP BY A.LDTime
ORDER BY A.LDTime
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out later this evening.  Hmmm, only one comment allowed every 15 seconds...waiting.

Comment: Goat CO and Gordon Linoff answered the question.  Goat's was 2 minutes sooner, so I'll give him (it?) the answer.  But both give identical results.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference appears to be the `where` clause.  So the following should label the rows correctly:

```
SELECT A.LDTime,A.Value,
       (case when F.StationIDx = 1 AND A.ParameterIdx = 18 then 'A'
             when A.ParameterIdx = 19 then 'B'
        end) as AorB
FROM         Table7 G INNER JOIN
Table1 A INNER JOIN
Table2 B ON A.DataSetIdx = B.DataSetIdx INNER JOIN
Table3 C ON B.RetrievalIdx = C.RetrievalIdx ON G.ActionIdx = C.ActionIdx INNER JOIN
Table4 D ON G.SpatialRefIdx = D.SpatialRefIdx INNER JOIN
Table5 E INNER JOIN
Table6 F ON E.StationIdx = F.StationIDx ON D.SpatialRefIdx = E.SpatialRefIdx
WHERE F.StationIDx = 1 AND A.ParameterIdx in (18, 19)
AND A.LDTime BETWEEN '2013-7-24' AND '2013-7-25'
ORDER BY A.LDTime
```

To do what you want, you need a `group by` on the query.  This gives you the results you want:

```
SELECT A.LDTime,
       max(case when A.ParameterIdx = 18 then Value end) as AValue,
       max(case when A.ParameterIdx = 19 then Value end) as BValue
FROM         Table7 G INNER JOIN
Table1 A INNER JOIN
Table2 B ON A.DataSetIdx = B.DataSetIdx INNER JOIN
Table3 C ON B.RetrievalIdx = C.RetrievalIdx ON G.ActionIdx = C.ActionIdx INNER JOIN
Table4 D ON G.SpatialRefIdx = D.SpatialRefIdx INNER JOIN
Table5 E INNER JOIN
Table6 F ON E.StationIdx = F.StationIDx ON D.SpatialRefIdx = E.SpatialRefIdx
WHERE F.StationIDx = 1 AND A.ParameterIdx in (18, 19)
AND A.LDTime BETWEEN '2013-7-24' AND '2013-7-25'
group BY A.LDTime
order by 1
```